# How to get gap between dates?

Tags: python, django, algorithm, datetime, django-models

I am making an app where you can assign tasks to person.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    TASK_CHOICES = (
        ('Task_1', 'Task_1'),
        ('Task_2', 'Task_2'),
        ('Task_3', 'Task_3'),
    )
    Person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=TASK_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.task
```

**My question is: How can I get the first date which is not assigned to any task?**

As you can see `2013-10-16` is not assigned to any task and I want get that date.

[image]

So far I tried to do some queryset.

`filtered_tasks = Task.objects.filter(person='HereHere', start_date_gte='2013-10-10').order_by('start_date')`

and then make a list of tuples.

`date_tuples = [(d.start_date, d.end_date) for d in filtered_tasks]` to get:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2013,10,10), datetime.datetime(2013,10,15),
(datetime.datetime(2013,10,17), datetime.datetime(2013,10,23),
(datetime.datetime(2013,10,24), datetime.datetime(2013,10,31)
]
```

As you can see there is a gap between `task2 start_date` and `task1 end_date`. And I'm stuck here, I don't know how to tell Python to get the date `(16.10)` where no tasks were assigned.

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand your question, but from what you said sounds like you are only trying to figure out if all entries in your query results are consecutive? If that's the case, you can do it in python like `if (datetime2 - datetime1).days > 1` to see if two datetimes objects have the difference of more than one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with dates in computers it is best to use a [closed-open notation](http://wrschneider.blogspot.com/2014/01/time-intervals-and-other-ranges-should.html). In other words the first date or datetime is the actual start but the end is listed as the first datetime not included in the set. In other words your data could look like this:

```
data = [(datetime.datetime(2013,10,10), datetime.datetime(2013,10,16)),
(datetime.datetime(2013,10,17), datetime.datetime(2013,10,24)),
(datetime.datetime(2013,10,24), datetime.datetime(2013,11,1)) 
]
```

Once you have your data in closed-open notation then you just need to get the interval of end dates minus the start dates:

```
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    if i > 0:
        if d[0] - data[i-1][1] > datetime.timedelta(0):
            print("Gap")
```

If you don't want to change to using closed-open just check for an interval greater than 1 day, but that will start causing you trouble down the road.

If you are using postgres 9.2+ you may want to look at using Range Types as they make this stuff easy inside the database.

Comment: But in your `data` there is no gap and your loop says that there is a 'Gap'

Comment: But you have two overlapped dates `2013,10,24` - In my app when I add tasks, there won't be overlapping dates.

Comment: Learn about Closed-Open Intervals, Also know as Half Open Intervals.
http://wrschneider.blogspot.com/2014/01/time-intervals-and-other-ranges-should.html